# Error while applying context TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReferences' of null Error

Tags: javascript, java, null, widget, mendix

Application throwing null error, tried a few things but no luck, seems something simple but cannot figure out for the life of me, not sure what I am missing. Hoping someone can see the problem.

** Log **

```
RouteToMarketSearch.RouteToMarketSearchSnippet.referenceSetDisplay2: Error while applying context Error: RouteToMarketSearch.RouteToMarketSearchSnippet.referenceSetDisplay2: Error while applying context TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReferences' of null Error: RouteToMarketSearch.RouteToMarketSearchSnippet.referenceSetDisplay2: Error while applying context Error: RouteToMarketSearch.RouteToMarketSearchSnippet.referenceSetDisplay2: Error while applying context TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReferences' of null
```

Declaring the variables

```
_handles: null,
_contextObj: null,
_reference : null,
_entity : null,
_intersectReference : null,
_intersectEntity : null,
```

** Code **

```
_updateRendering: function (callback) {
    logger.debug(this.id + "._updateRendering");
    var self = this;
    if(this.rsdListContainer){
        data.get({
            guids: this._contextObj.getReferences(this._reference),
            callback: function(objs){
                if(self.rsdListContainer){
                    var intersectGuids = [];
                    if(self._intersectReference){
                        intersectGuids = self._contextObj.getReferences(self._intersectReference);
                    }

                    var dataArray = objs.map(function(o){
                        var data = {};
                        data.guid = o.getGuid();
                        data.caption = o.get(self.displayAttribute);
                        if( intersectGuids && intersectGuids.indexOf(o.getGuid()) > -1){
                            data.elementClass = self.intersetResultClass;
                        }
                        if(self.sortAttribute){
                            data.sortIndex = parseInt(o.get(self.sortAttribute));
                        }

                        return data;
                    });

                    if(self.sortAttribute){
                        dataArray.sort(function(a,b){
                                return a.sortIndex - b.sortIndex;
                        });
                    }

                    dojoConstruct.empty(self.rsdListContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring `_contextObj` with a null value, when you try to execute `this._contextObj.getReferences` throws that error. There is no internal implementation of a null value, you would need to declare it or condition its access

Comment: I tried initializing it but that didn't work, I'll try conditioning it's access.

Comment: Try with a console.log after initializing and check if "getReferences" function exists

Comment: I think I am probably declaring the variable wrong, is this the correct way this._contextObj = ' ';?

Comment: `if (this.rsdListContainer && this._contextObj) {` should do the trick.

Comment: @EdLucas you are a genius. 'FULL STOP'. I was trying to condition it's access but was in the wrong part.